# Do Ronnie and Dr. Stein have to be in the same room to become Firestorm?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

In the new Flash series is it possible for Ronnie and Professor Stein to be in seperate locations and still merge into Firestorm?

Answer (score 1):

Ronnie and Dr. Stein can feel each other from separate locations, but they can't merge into Firestorm without coming near each other.

If they could merge into Firestorm from separate location, freeing Dr. Stein wouldn't have been difficult when he was kidnapped.

Comment: Good point- I guess since Ronnie's given up for gone and the Doc's linked (for lack of a better word) in season 2 the question's kind of moot.